# Slider is not properly working when width is 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a slider with `width: 100%` of the parent.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/gna7r4L8/29/).

```
 .moving_container ul li {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
 /* background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;*/
 }
```

It's working fine now. When i set width 100%, I am not getting the slider view as in width 500px. What is the correct property so that this slider works in all the sized windows.

I just played with background-properties. Unfortunately I din't get it.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: A possible solution is to add a new function in your js code. When the page load and resize, call a function to reset the with of the slider as the body with is. In other words, set the 100% width with js, not in CSS.

Comment: I don't think that could make differences. Please let me know how it will solve the issue. I am free to modify anything. That's why i added 4 tags here. Desired solution is getting a slider which works in almost all sized windows

Comment: Set the ".moving_container" and the list element "slide1" and "slide2" width equal to the $(window).with().

Comment: I don't want to add carousel

Answer (score 3):

Add this on top of your JS Function:

```
$('.moving_container li').width($(window).width());
```

Comment: Use it it also in a function called on window resize.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Yes. But i think i need to recalculate all the width in js. It's still adding problems if i do so

Comment: @Gops AB: it is the only way if you need a really responsive slider.